# Detect Swipe direction using React Native Gesture Handler and Reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

We have already developed a swiper using React Native PanResponder, (before somebody comment) - we cannot use any other swiper library here. In the swiper we developed, we are facing an issue when a user ends the swipe(meaning releases the Pan) there is a lag when starting a spring animation.

So to fix that, we are trying to move from [React Native Animated API](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated#event) to [Reanimated Libary](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated) which could solve the problem of lag the user is facing.

> But while developing with [React Native Gesture Handler](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler) (PanGestureHandler) and
>   Reanimated Library, we're unable to detect swipe direction in the
>   gesture handler.

I'm adding the part of code which we used to detect swipe direction in PanResponder

```
onPanMoving = (evt, {dx}) => {
   this.draggedEnd = dx < -this.swipeThreshold; //You are moving towards right screen
   this.draggedStart = dx > this.swipeThreshold; //You are moving towards left screen
}
```

As you see, detecting the direction while the pan is moving was so easy in PanResponder.

> Here comes the problem with Gesture Handler,
>
> I'm unable to detect swipe while the gesture state is active

I have already searched for issues in Gesture Handler and I found [this](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/265).

There were two workaround suggested in the issue

1. First one is by [Sonaye](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/265#issuecomment-410304603) which has two handler and detects the
   swipe direction in **onHandlerStateChange** for both the handlers
   which was not helpful while using reanimated because it only sets swipe direction
   when handlers state changes.
2. Second one is by [Satya](https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-gesture-handler/pull/265#issuecomment-458898165) which actually detects the swipe when
   the State is ACTIVE but he uses **translationX** property, the
   translationX property can also negative for us and can move in
   either direction similar to swiper.

Both the workarounds doesn't solve our problem.

So is there any other way to find direction using PanGestureHandler and Reanimated. I tried using PanResponder with Reanimated with **dx** value but ended up with error message i.e nativeEvent properties are only support as **dx** is from gestureState param from PanResponder.

Note: We cannot use **[FlingGestureHandler](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/handler-fling.html)** and **[Swipeables](https://kmagiera.github.io/react-native-gesture-handler/docs/component-swipeable.html)** because we need to find direction in Fling still onHandlerStateChange and Swipeables doesn't use Reanimated.

Answer (score 8):

You can detect direction when swipe horizontal via property `velocityX`

Example :

```
const handleGesture = (evt) => {
    const { nativeEvent } = evt;

    if (nativeEvent.velocityX > 0) {
      console.log('Swipe right');
    } else {
      console.log('Swipe left');
    }
  };

return (
   <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handleGesture}>
       // child component
   </PanGestureHandler>
);
```

Comment: `translationX`/`translationY` are the ones your're looking for if you need to know the distance swiped

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use double `FlingGestureHandler` to have vertical or horizontal fling gesture here is the solution:

First you have to initialize the `stateHandlers` for the direction you want. In my case, i was trying to implement a vertical `flingGestureHandler`.

```
  const onDownFlingHandlerStateChange = ({
    nativeEvent,
  }: FlingGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent) => {
    if (nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      progressHeight.value = withTiming(COLLAPSED_HEIGHT, {
        duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
      });
    }
  };

  const onUpFlingHandlerStateChange = ({
    nativeEvent,
  }: FlingGestureHandlerStateChangeEvent) => {
    if (nativeEvent.oldState === State.ACTIVE) {
      progressHeight.value = withTiming(
        DEVICE_HEIGHT - TOP_PADDING_FOR_EXPANDED,
        {
          duration: ANIMATION_DURATION,
        },
      );
    }
  };
```

and then you have to bind those handlers to 2 `FlingGestureHandler` component of RNGH

```
<FlingGestureHandler
  onHandlerStateChange={onUpFlingHandlerStateChange}
  onEnded={() => {
     onPressChecklistIcon();
  }}
  direction={Directions.UP}>
  <FlingGestureHandler
    direction={Directions.DOWN}
    onEnded={() => {
      onPressChecklistIcon();
    }}
    onHandlerStateChange={onDownFlingHandlerStateChange}>
    <Animated.View style={[styles.container, reanimatedStyle]}>
      <View style={styles.closerContainer}>
        <View style={styles.closer} />
      </View>
      {renderChecklistContent()}
    </Animated.View>
  </FlingGestureHandler>
</FlingGestureHandler>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use translationX property rather than velocityX property by nativeEvent:

```js
 const handleGesture = (evt) => {
    const { nativeEvent } = evt;
    if (nativeEvent.translationX > 0) {
      Alert.alert('Swipe right');
    } else {
      Alert.alert('Swipe left');
    }
  };
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case I have used double `FlingGestureHandler` to detect the direction. It's worked for me.

Comment: *double FlingGestureHandlers

Comment: Please note that you can always [edit] your answer. So there's no need to use comments to update your answer.